# Implementing a breadcrumb into your SharePoint 2010 website?

Tags: sharepoint, web, sharepoint-2010, breadcrumbs

Has anybody any sample code or excellent article links showing an implementation of a breadcrumb navigation into a SharePoint 2010 Website?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Technet says [this](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee695757.aspx#Section2c)
Breadcrumb navigation displays a dynamically generated set of links at the top of Web pages, to show users their current position in the site hierarchy. By using SharePoint Designer 2010 or Visual Studio 2010, you can configure the breadcrumb navigation control. For example, you can specify a custom navigation provider, and you can remove breadcrumb navigation from a page layout.

This [article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms558975.aspx) discusses creating a custom navigation provider.

This is a control that you can add to sharepoint found on CodePlex ([mavention](http://mavention.codeplex.com/releases/view/43361))

Answer (score 1):

OK,

here is a short HowTo for the [mavention-breadcrumb](http://blog.mastykarz.nl/create-sharepoint-breadcrumbs-mavention-simple-sitemappath/) deployment. 
I had some problems doing it the way it's described on the blog and asked the developer for help.

So

1) copy the maventionsimplesitemappath.wsp solution to your website's BIN-Directory 
2) add the wsp-solution over the sp_powershell (stsadm -0 addsolution …)
3) GoTo central server administration/farm solutions and deploy the solution we  just added before
4) open the website's masterpage in sp_designer(or other) and insert the register- and control-code (you can copy/paste it from the blog above)

that's it!

If you still got porblems with permissions like I had some days ago try this(tipp from the solution-developer & blog owner)

- open the website's web.config and search for the line `<trustLevel name="WSS_Custom"..`
- open the policy file you can find in this line (wss_custom_wss_minimaltrust.config)
- find lines `<CodeGroup ...>` maventionsimplesitemappath.wsp should be mentioned here `</CodeGroup>`
- `<CodeGroup class="FirstMatchCodeGroup" version="1" PermissionSetName="Nothing">`
  change the PermissionSetName to "FullTrust" if it's on "Nothing"

hope your permission-problems are solved now